# Error Code: 1366. Incorrect integer value: '#N/A' for column 'Length' at row 21

Tags: mysql

In my dataset, there are many nonsense values of "#N/A". I create a new table and load the local CSV file into my new table. But because of the nonsense value, it shows the error as shown in the headline. How can I load a dataset successfully without the nonsense values?

Here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE movies (
    Yearnum INT NOT NULL,
    Length INT,
    Title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Subjct VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Actor VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Actress VARCHAR(255) ,
    Director VARCHAR(255) ,
    Popularity VARCHAR(255),
    Awards VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
LOAD DATA INFILE  'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/movies - movies.csv'
INTO TABLE movies
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

Here is my link url of dataset:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J17LYPJZaW5QWQuQVJQonpJXGUbPGOJjg5bxj3SMupQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: then remove th #nva from the sourceit is easier than to write a rewriting in sql

Comment: Another solution load teh file into another table that accepts vahrchar at length and use a insert into movies SELECT * From mytemtable where you replace the unwanted text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work around this by using a column list with variables in the place of columns whose data might not be valid in the CSV file; the column values can then be made valid using a `SET` clause. For your example:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE  'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/movies - movies.csv'
INTO TABLE movies
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(Yearnum, @length, Title, Subjct, Actor, Actress, Director, Popularity, Awards)
SET Length = CASE WHEN @length = '#N/A' THEN 0 ELSE @length END
```

See the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html#load-data-input-preprocessing) for more details.

Comment: Even though this answer solves this particular issue, it is just a poor workaround. There should be a proper ETL process in place with data quality rules embedded into it.

Comment: @Shadow the fact that OP doesn't have that in place doesn't make this an incorrect answer that deserves a downvote... I specifically state this is a workaround in the answer.